# Why does this regex not work in VB.NET?

Tags: .net, regex, vb.net

I have a regular expression;

```
        mtch = Regex.Match(address, "^(APT|APARTMENT|SUITE|STE|UNIT)( )?(NUMBER|NO|#)? ([0-9A-Z\-]+)( )(.*)$")
```

whose purpose is to identify apartment numbers at the start of a string. I have tested it with [My Regex tester](https://www.myregextester.com/index.php)

And it seems to work. When I test it in VB.NET (VS2010) it works in most cases, but it has a problem with "#" in the apartment number.

```
"APT 101 202 SW 303 ST" - matches
"APT NO 101 202 SW 303 ST" - matches
"APT NUMBER 101 202 SW 303 ST" - matches
"APARTMENT NUMBER 101 202 SW 303 ST" - matches
"APARTMENT # 101 202 SW 303 ST" - **no match**
"APT # 101 202 SW 303 ST" - **no match**
```

Regex, as the saying goes "...like the jitterbug it plumb eluded me."

Edit-

For anyone finding this, I had code that would replace "#" with " # " before the regex in the program. I am trying to add the code to handle multiple spaces now. If you have a suggestion chime in.

Comment: Works for me in VS. Are you sure that the Regex tester you are using is .Net compliant? There are different flavours of regex with different languages

Comment: Works for me too in VB. Please post a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem. (Perhaps your input isn't actually what you think it is? Maybe it contains an "invisible" character?)

Comment: I see my problem. I have code that adds spaces around #s and before it gets to the regex it is "APT  #  101 202 SW 303 ST" two spaces before & after the #. I will try to account for multiple spaces. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You have to match multiple spaces:

```
mtch = Regex.Match(address, "^(APT|APARTMENT|SUITE|STE|UNIT) *(NUMBER|NO|#)? *([0-9A-Z-]+) (.*)$")
#                                                     here __^         and __^
```